# How to use timer for writing a new file with data everyday in Visual C++

Tags: visual-c++, timer

I have the source code of a VC++ 6.0 application that is used to communicate with a medical device and want it to modify such that the application creates a new file to dump data as the system date changes. I have no prior experience with Visual C++ and have just read that the timer class can be useful. Following is a stub from the code,

```
CXYZClientTestDlg::CXYZClientTestDlg(CWnd* pParent /*=NULL*/)
: CDialog(CXYZlientTestDlg::IDD, pParent)
,m_pEditConnectStatus(NULL)
,m_pEditMsgDisplay(NULL)
,LOG_FILE_PATH_PARAMS ("C:/MyPath/Needs to be a new file Everyday.txt")
,m_AppNumber(_T(""))

//  Code for querying the data from the machine //

// write to file
DumpFile( LOG_FILE_PATH_PARAMS , (unsigned char*)&szBuffer[0] , iReturn );
```

Basically, I need to keep changing the LOG_FILE_PATH_PARAMS every day (perhaps using a timer) so that a new DumpFile is created. Please help me solve this as I have no experience in VC++.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Define Timer ID in your header file.

```
const int TIMER_ID = 1;
```

Add below as a member variable.

```
CTime oldTime;
```

At OnInitDialog() set the first timer. Timer handler will be invoked at next o'clock.

```
oldTime = CTime::GetCurrentTime();

int time_to_next =  ( 60 * 60 ) - ( oldTime.GetMinute() * 60 + oldTime.GetSecond() );
SetTimer( TIMER_ID, time_to_next * 1000, NULL );
```

Add OnTimer event handler and check if the date is changed.
Do something and set next timer timing.

```
void CTestDlg::OnTimer(UINT_PTR nIDEvent)
{
    CTime nowTime = CTime::GetCurrentTime();

    if( nowTime.GetDay() != oldTime.GetDay() )
    {
        CString filename;
        filename.Format(_T("Path/to/the/file/%4d_%02d_%02d_blabla.txt"),
            nowTime.GetYear(), nowTime.GetMonth(), nowTime.GetDay());

        // save with the filename
        oldTime = nowTime;
    }

    nowTime = CTime::GetCurrentTime();
    int time_to_next =  ( 60 * 60 ) - ( nowTime.GetMinute() * 60 + nowTime.GetSecond() );
    SetTimer( TIMER_ID, time_to_next * 1000, NULL );

    CDialog::OnTimer(nIDEvent);
}
```

Comment: Thanks Jin, that was very helpful!